# Some misunderstanding using jQuery files[].size function with and ASP.NET FileUpload control.

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to Jquery and ASP.NET so maybe my question will seem naive to some of you.

I need to check file size before upload it to the server.

I have this ASP.NET code:

```
        <div class="label">
            Select file           
        </div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileAsyncUpload" runat="server" Width="270" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="GetFileSize()" />
    </div>
```

I have this jquery functions:

```
function GetFileSize() {
    try {
        var fileSize = 0;
        fileSize = $("#" + '<%= fileAsyncUpload.ClientID %>')[0].files[0].size;
        fileSize = fileSize / 1048576;
        confirm("Upload file size is :" + fileSize + "Mb")

    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error is:" + e);
    }
}
```

I googled and found the function **GetFileSize()** above.

But I cant understand this row:

```
$("#" + '<%= fileAsyncUpload.ClientID %>')[0].files[0].size;
```

How does it knows file size?
Does it load to browser and then check the size of the file?
Or it check the size on client computer?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp see this link

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications check this link also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetFileSize` function runs in your browser (not on your IIS server). That's a javascript function, which also considered as a **[client script](http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/)**.

When the users finish selecting the file that they want to upload with `<input type=file>` element, the browser has performed such as handshake operation which lets the selected *file's attributes* are readable by the browser. So, it wouldn't be weird if the browser can read the size, would it?

Basically, your ASP.Net markup will render something like this but not exact in HTML,

```
<div class="label">
    Select file           
    </div>
        <input type='file' id='ctl00$YourParentControlsOrNot$fileSyncUpload' />
        <input type='submit' id='ctl00$YourParentControlsOrNot$Button1' onclick='GetFileSize()' onsubmit='ctl00$blablabla'>Upload</input>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note: Ignore the element IDs, they're assigned like that if you set your `ClientIDMode` to `AutoID`, otherwise It'd look like `YourParentControl_Button1` if you set it to `Predictable` or even just `Button1` if you set it to `Static`.*

```
// This returns your FileUpload control client id, which can be used with javascript.
<%= fileAsyncUpload.ClientID %> 

// This will make it as a javascript element. (Not jQuery),
$("#" + '<%= fileAsyncUpload.ClientID %>')[0] 

// This will return the size of that file.
$("#" + '<%= fileAsyncUpload.ClientID %>')[0].files[0].size
```

The same case with [**This sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/rue1o47p/).

Comment: As you can see I don't use HTML5 <input type=file> I use ASP.NET  FileUpload control.Is it works the same?

Comment: ASP.NET FileUpload control will render as `<input type=file>` in HTML. Just right click and inspect your FileUpload control element. I'll add details to my answer.